# Monk recommends: knock down women on sight

Tags: translation

I read today:

> Ein weiser Möch sagte einst: "Wenn deine Augen eine Frau erblicken, schlage sie nieder"

Am I misunderstanding something?
Because it is kind of hard to consider knocking down woman as soon as your eyes caught a glimpse of her good advice!

Comment: I am surprised this question has not made it to the hot network questions yet due to dozens of people visiting it just to find out what’s behind this title.

Comment: The German sentence just made my day. I didn't get it until I read hellcode's answer - and I am German... :-)

Answer (score 22):

It is an example of ambiguity. The real meaning of "schlage sie nieder" in this sentence is to look (bashfully) at the ground (open eyes = Augen aufschlagen, look at the ground = Augen niederschlagen), but the first thing you normally think is what you wrote, because nearly nobody uses "Augen niederschlagen" (maybe you would say: "schaue verlegen auf den Boden")

See also [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehrdeutigkeit):

> Alte Mönchsregel: Wenn deine Augen eine Frau erblicken, schlage sie
>   nieder.  (Das Wort „sie“ bezieht sich syntaktisch auf das Subjekt des
>   Satzes, also „die Augen“, nach der üblichen Betonung aber auf „die
>   Frau“; diese syntaktische Doppeldeutigkeit ist nur möglich, weil das
>   Wort „sie“ semantisch ein Femininum im Singular oder einen Plural
>   bezeichnen kann.)

Comment: "Die Augen niederschlagen" means "to look down", not "to close one's eyes".

Comment: For me, "the first thing [I] normally think" (in the german sentence) was the meaning of "to look down". And I find this quite "normally"... What's going on in this country?